# Three variable calculation

Tags: linear-algebra

David's truck can load 28tons and 70m³ of cargo and it costs USD19600 to move from point A to point B. Mike wants to send his washing machine from point A to point B by David's truck. Washing machine's weight is 300kg, and it's volume is 1m³.

How much should David charge Mike?

Cost for every kg= USD19600/28000kg= USD0.7/kg

Cost for every m³= USD19600/70m³= USD280/m³

Cost by weight= 300kg * USD0.7/kg= USD210

Cost by volume= 1m³ * USD280/m³= USD280

As we see, we have two different costs here: USD210 by weight, and USD280 by volume.
But I want to find the "perfect" cost. I think X should be somewhere between USD210 and USD280. So, this should be true: USD210 < X < USD280.

I guess this is something related with three variable relationship (cost, weight and volume), and we should use linear algebra to solve the problem.

1. Is there a way to find the "perfect" cost?
2. What is the formula to calculate the cost?

Note: David is a cargo company, he has many other clients. So he also should use the formula to charge other clients accordingly. And David has many trucks, as soon as one truck is full by weight or volume, he can start loading his another truck. But the sum of collected money from his customers should be equal to USD19600 for every truck. Let's don't take into account possible holes between goods.

In other words, if we  reduce 70m³, 28000kg, and USD19600 by 70 we get 1m³, 400kg and USD280 respectively.

So, if 1m³ and 400kg costs USD280,

Then how much should 1m³ and 300kg cost?

Simple proportion doesn't help here. Because the heavier the goods are cost per kg goes down, and cost per m³ goes up. The lighter the goods are cost per kg goes up, and cost per m³ goes down.

Comment: It rather depends on whether David has anything else to move (if not then the cost should be $\$19600$) and what David would have to not move to enable Mike's washing machine to fit.

Comment: David is a cargo company he has other clients. So he also should use the formula to charge them accordingly.

Comment: Yep, you need additional hypotheses on what other cargo David can expect to be offered for transport, like a joint probability distribution on volume and weight. And you need to assign a cost to waiting for the next customer, otherwise David is better off waiting indefinitely until some very small package arrives to fill up the last hole in his truck.

Comment: Let's assume he has many clients and that small package is available very soon. And let's don't take into account the waiting cost.

Answer (score 0):

We have:
19600 USD ---- 28000 kg ---- 70 m3
That is, we can consider 400 kg/m3 as specific weight (SP).

Considering weight:

19390 USD ---- 27700 kg -----  SP = 401,4 kg/m3

00210 USD ---- 00300 kg -----  SP = 300,0 kg/m3

Considering volume:

19320 USD ---- 69 m3 ----- SP = 401,4 kg/m3

00280 USD ---- 01 m3 ----- SP = 300,0 kg/m3

If density or specific weight is less than 400 kg/m3
*- if seller, consider volume
*- if buyer, consider weight

If density or specific weight is more than 400 kg/m3
*- if seller, consider weight
*- if buyer, consider volume

Let's say we have 70 people with 70 washing machines to transport.
We have 70 m3 (full truck) and 21000 kg (less than 28000 kg).
What do we do?
We achieved volume but not weight.

Let's say we have 56 washing machines with 500 kg each to transport.
We have 28000 kg (full truck) and 56 m3 (less than 70 m3).
What do we do?
We achieved weight but not volume.